# Removing rows from dataframe whose first letter is in lowercase

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like -

```
    FileName        PageNo     LineNo   EntityName  
1   17743633 - 1    TM000002    69      Ambuja Cement Limited
2   17743633 - 1    TM000003    14      Vessel Name
3   17743633 - 1    TM000003    12      tyre Chips (Shredded Tyres)
4   17743633 - 1    TM000006    22      ambuja Cement Limited
5   17743633 - 1    TM000006    28      Binani Cement Limited
```

I have to remove those rows from the datframe in which EntityName column's first letter is lowercase. i.e I have to retain values that start with a upper case.

I have used to methods till now -

```
df['EntityName'] = map(lambda x: x[0].isupper(), df['EntityName'])
```

but it is giving NaN values.

another thing that i tried was regex.

```
df['EntityName'] = df['EntityName'].str.replace('^[a-z]+$','')
```

but it is showing no effect.

another one was -

```
qw = df.EntityName.str[0]
df = df[qw.isupper()]
```

but it is showing error -

> 'Series' object has no attribute 'isupper'

Can someone suggest me the correct code snippet or any kind of hint?

Comment: i have found a solution for this as -
df = df[df.EntityName.apply(lambda x: x[0].isupper())]

Comment: if anyone has a solution with less execution time then please share.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First select first letter by indexing and then check [`isupper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isupper.html) or [`islower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.islower.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['EntityName'].str[0].str.isupper()]
#for working with NaN and None
#df = df[df['EntityName'].str[0].str.isupper().fillna(False)]
```

Or:

```
df = df[~df['EntityName'].str[0].str.islower()]
#for working with NaN and None
df = df[~df['EntityName'].str[0].str.islower().fillna(False)]
```

Or use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex - `^` is for match first value of string:

```
df = df[df['EntityName'].str.contains('^[A-Z]+')]
```

Solution if no `NaN`s in data is list comprehension:

```
df = df[[x[0].isupper() for x in df['EntityName']]]
```

More general solution working with empty strings and `NaN`s is add `if-else`:

```
mask = [x[0].isupper() if isinstance(x,str) and len(x)>0 else False for x in df['EntityName']]
df = df[mask]
```

---

```
print (df)
              FileName          ...                       EntityName
1 17743633 -         1          ...            Ambuja Cement Limited
2 17743633 -         1          ...                      Vessel Name
5 17743633 -         1          ...            Binani Cement Limited
```

Comment: To make the `NaN` handling useful with `pandas`, you may need to add `.fillna(False)` (for additional cost).

Comment: Yes, like `df = df[df['EntityName'].str[0].str.isupper().fillna(False)]`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the data I think `istitle` would do your work i.e

```
df[df['EntityName'].str.istitle()]

      FileName    PageNo  LineNo             EntityName
1  17743633 - 1  TM000002      69  Ambuja Cement Limited
2  17743633 - 1  TM000003      14            Vessel Name
5  17743633 - 1  TM000006      28  Binani Cement Limited
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df[df.EntityName.str[0].str.isupper()]
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance, consider indexing with a simple list comprehension and accessing the `numpy` array representation of your series:

```
df = df[[i[0].isupper() for i in df['EntityName'].values]]
```

This solution will work if you do not expect any empty strings in your series.

**Performance benchmarking**

```
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller

s = pd.Series(['Hello', 'hello', 'test', 'Test'])

def jpp(s):
    return list(map(methodcaller('isupper'), map(itemgetter(0), s.values)))

def jpp2(s):
    return [i[0].isupper() for i in s.values]

def jez(s):
    return s.str[0].str.isupper()

s = pd.concat([s]*100000)

%timeit jpp(s)   # 116 ms per loop
%timeit jpp2(s)  # 82 ms per loop
%timeit jez(s)   # 313 ms per loop
```

Comment: Yes, it is expected because no `NaN`s :)

Comment: I add `df = df[[x[0].isupper() for x in df['EntityName']]]` to answer, it is slowier as `df[[i[0].isupper() for i in df['EntityName'].values]]` ?

Comment: @jezrael, Sure, no problem :)